# gem which cannot find gem despite it being installed

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I've built my first gem but I don't seem to be able to get it to install correctly. I can issue the command

```
sudo gem install ceilingfish-toto
```

Which produces the output

```
Successfully installed ceilingfish-toto-0.3.6
1 gem installed
```

But when I then type `gem which ceilingfish-toto`. I get the output

```
Can't find ruby library file or shared library ceilingfish-toto
```

Which is very strange because if I go and look in my gems folder I can see all the files installed there

```
# ls -l /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/ceilingfish-toto-0.3.6/
total 48
-rw-r--r--  1 root  admin  1053 14 Feb 17:16 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--  1 root  admin  6166 14 Feb 17:16 README.md
-rw-r--r--  1 root  admin   879 14 Feb 17:16 Rakefile
-rw-r--r--  1 root  admin     6 14 Feb 17:16 VERSION
-rw-r--r--  1 root  admin  2477 14 Feb 17:16 ceilingfish-toto.gemspec
drwxr-xr-x  7 root  admin   238 14 Feb 17:16 test
```

Does anyone know what could cause this? I think it's complaining because there is a hyphen in the gem name. You can see the gemspec here http://github.com/ceilingfish/toto

Comment: Well, there indeed is no `ceilingfish-toto` file or shared library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`gem which ceilingfish-toto` looks through the gem require path for a file named ceilingfish-toto.rb. Since there isn't one, it returns nothing. What would work for you is `gem which toto`, but since `lib/` is not included in your gem spec, the lib files are not installed, so it doesn't exist.

Rerunning `rake gemspec` might fix the problem.

As an aside, you can check whether a gem is installed by its name by using `gem list ceilingfish-toto` which should show you it is installed, regardless of the files it has(it will also list the versions installed).

Comment: For 'gem list', use _-d_ for "details": `gem list -d ceilingfish-toto` to see where it is installed.

Answer (score 9):

It's not the hyphen.

`gem which` searches for **library files in gems, not gems**. Compare:

```
$ gem which haml
/home/dave/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/haml-3.0.12/lib/haml.rb
$ ls haml-3.0.12/lib/h*
haml  haml.rb  haml.rbc
```

Peachy. Note the existance of `lib/haml.rb`.

```
$ gem which rails
ERROR:  Can't find ruby library file or shared library rails
$ ls rails-2.3.8/lib/r*
rails_generator.rb  railties_path.rb  rubyprof_ext.rb  ruby_version_check.rb
```

There is no `lib/rails.rb`. But try:

```
$ gem which railties_path # not a gem
/home/dave/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.8/lib/railties_path.rb
```

So `gem which ceilingfish-toto` throws an error even when `ceilingfish-toto` is installed because there is no `lib/ceilingfish-toto.rb` file (there's not even a `lib` folder).

Answer (score 1):

According to the [gem naming recommendations](https://guides.rubygems.org/name-your-gem/):

> If you’re adding functionality to another gem, use a dash. This usually corresponds to a / in the require statement (and therefore your gem’s directory structure) and a :: in the name of your main class or module.

If this is the case, if your gem is named alpha-beta you need to add a slash (/) to the gem which command

```
gem which alpha/beta
```

Comment: this is really messed up.  it should do this automatically.  just wasted 1/2-hr.