# Unable to require gem from git with RVM

Tags: ruby, git, rubygems

I cannot require a custom gem I developed to a ruby project. I use RVM. Here's what I've done:

I added gem locally via Gemfile:

```
gem 'my-gem', git: 'https://github.com/username/my-gem.git'
```

I installed the gem:

```
bundle
Fetching https://github.com/username/my-gem.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using my-gem 0.1.0 https://github.com/username/my-gem.git (at master@dcdac02)
Using bundler 1.11.2
Bundle complete! 1 Gemfile dependency, 2 gems now installed.
```

I confirmed it was installed:

```
bundle show my-gem
/Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bundler/gems/my-gem-dcdac02a8b69
```

I confirmed my gem paths:

```
GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2
     - /Users/myuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global
```

When I run `gem list`, my gem is **missing**. When I `require 'my-gem'`, the gem cannot be found.

When I run `gem which my-gem`, I get:

```
ERROR:  Can't find ruby library file or shared library my-gem
```

I'm not really sure what else to try. Any ideas?

Comment: may be you installed the gem in another rvm gemset?

Comment: @uDaY `rvm gemset list` shows the same path as GEM PATHS in `gem environment`

Answer (score 1):

Rubygems have no concept of git installed gems, so Bundler includes a specific mechanism for loading these paths into the GEMPATH, you need to do the following before you can require them:

```rb
require 'bundler'
Bundler.setup
```

See the [Bundler git gems docs](https://bundler.io/guides/git.html#how-to-install-gems-from-git-repositories) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure the installed version of the gem has all the files you expect, especially `lib` and its contents. This past discussion might help you:

[gem which cannot find gem despite it being installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261981/gem-which-cannot-find-gem-despite-it-being-installed)

Comment: The only thing in `~/.bundle/config` is ---
BUNDLE_GEM__TEST: rspec
BUNDLE_GEM__MIT: false
BUNDLE_GEM__COC: false. Trying to require the file using `bundle exec` makes no difference - still doesn't work.

Comment: What happens when you type `bundle config`?

Comment: It lists the same settings pasted above.

Comment: Okay, the `bundler` dir was a red herring, edited my answer with a more likely cause.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar issue

```
bundle show kubernetes_metadata_filter

/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bundler/gems/fluent-plugin-kubernetes_metadata_filter-0cd7e29eacec
```

while the rest of my gems were install here:

```
/fluentd/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/
```

notice the subtle difference between 2.3.0/bundler/gems/... and 2.3.0/gems/......

HACKY SOLUTION:
after bundle install, i did the following:

```
gem install specific_install
gem specific_install -l <url to a github gem>
```

That did the trick and installed the gem to the gems directory, and not just bundler. I beleive the correct fix is the project needs to  require bundler on startup, then it will get the bundler installed gems as well, but not all projects are well suited for that solution.  good luck!